# Django: How to create a queryset from raw?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a query which seems to be hard to do using Django conventions by using `filter()` or `extra()`. In that way i think that performing a raw SQL query and transform that into queryset is a better solution for me.

For that reason i started to search how to perform a raw SQL query and how to create a queryset from raw.

i found this solution from [CaryMRobbins](https://gist.github.com/carymrobbins/8477219) to convert raw to queryset. So i decided to put this in my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import connection, models

class MyManager(Manager):

def raw_as_qs(self, raw_query, params=()):
"""Execute a raw query and return a QuerySet. The first column in the
result set must be the id field for the model.
:type raw_query: str | unicode
:type params: tuple[T] | dict[str | unicode, T]
:rtype: django.db.models.query.QuerySet
"""
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  try:
    cursor.execute(raw_query, params)
    return self.filter(id__in=(x[0] for x in cursor))
  finally:
    cursor.close()

class MyModel(models.Model):
  objects = MyManager()
```

But it seems to not work properly because it returns a queryset empty.

In `views.py` i add the following script:

```
raw =  ''' My huge 
           query working'''
queryset = MyModel.objects.raw_as_qs(raw)
print queryset # result is empty list : []
```

Following this approach what am i missing?

I'm having some difficult to understand how `return self.filter(id__in=(x[0] for x in cursor))` works to convert into qs.

Comment: Can you post your models and explain the query you want to perform ?

Comment: Did you try `MyModel.objects.raw(raw)`

Comment: yes, it returns a RawQuerySet.

Comment: Does your `My huge query working` has the ID as the first column in the result set? If you use any sql-profiling tool, you might notice that it isn't the very optimal way to solve the problem - it doubles the number of queries and uses `in` operator. 
`MyModel.objects.raw(raw)` will give you `RawQuerySet`, but it is similar to `QuerySet` as it provides an iterator which converts the results of raw SQL queries into annotated model instances, but with some limitations due to unmanaged nature of raw queries (for instance, it has no `count()` implementation)

Comment: yes it has integer that doesn't repeat result from a query, but it doesn't have a sequencial id. RawQuerySet has no .values(), first(), or .filter() like queryset has which for me is important to apply in others apps already made which expect a QuerySet format.